# java.lang.NullPointerException error, when running code on my computer but not on my friends

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I keep getting the java.lang.NullPointerException error when trying to run my code, however I do know that there should not be any errors for it works on a friends computer. I'm using Eclipse, and cannot seem to find the problem. Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong, perhaps with the settings? Thanks

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {

public static List< Account > accounts;
public static List< ICommand > commands;

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    commands.add( new CreateNewCommand() );
    commands.add( new OpenAccountCommand() );
    commands.add( new MakePaymentCommand() );
    commands.add( new IncrementMonthCommand() );

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    boolean run = true;

    while ( run ) {
        System.out.println( "Commands:" );

        for ( ICommand command : commands ) {
            if ( command instanceof CreateNewCommand )
                System.out.println( ( ( CreateNewCommand )command ).command );

            if ( command instanceof OpenAccountCommand )
                System.out.println( ( ( OpenAccountCommand )command ).command );

            if ( command instanceof MakePaymentCommand )
                System.out.println( ( ( MakePaymentCommand )command ).command );

            if ( command instanceof IncrementMonthCommand )
                System.out.println( ( ( IncrementMonthCommand )command ).command );
        }

        // Close account is the same as open account, so no extra classes needed.
        System.out.println( "CloseAccount" );

        System.out.println();

        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] inputArgs = line.split( "\\s+" );

        switch ( inputArgs[ 0 ] ) {
        case "CreateNew":
            CreateNewStruct structData0 = new CreateNewStruct();
            structData0.name = inputArgs[ 1 ];
            structData0.address = inputArgs[ 2 ];
            structData0.phone = inputArgs[ 3 ];
            structData0.ssn = inputArgs[ 4 ];
            structData0.age = inputArgs[ 5 ];
            structData0.initialBalance = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 6 ] );
            structData0.loanLen = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 7 ] );
            structData0.credit = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 8 ] );

            structData0 = ( CreateNewStruct ) ( ( CreateNewCommand ) commands.get( 0 ) ).DoCommand( ( Object ) structData0 );
            accounts.add( structData0.account );
            System.out.println( "Account #" + structData0.account.acntNum + " was created." );
            break;

        case "OpenAccount":
            OpenAccountStruct structData1 = new OpenAccountStruct();
            structData1.acntNum = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] );
            structData1.accounts = accounts;

            structData1 = ( OpenAccountStruct ) ( ( OpenAccountCommand ) commands.get( 1 ) ).DoCommand( ( Object ) structData1 );

            if ( structData1 == null ) {
                System.out.println( "Could not find account #" + Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] ) + "." );
                break;
            }

            Account account1 = structData1.account;

            System.out.println( "Account Number: " + account1.acntNum );
            System.out.println( "Name: " + account1.name );
            System.out.println( "Address: " + account1.address );
            System.out.println( "Phone: " + account1.phone );
            System.out.println( "SSN: " + account1.ssn );
            System.out.println( "Age: " + account1.age );
            System.out.println( "Initial Balance: " + account1.initialBalance );
            System.out.println( "Loan Length: " + account1.loanLen );
            System.out.println( "Credit: " + account1.credit );
            System.out.println( "Monthly Payment: " + account1.monthlyPayment );
            System.out.println( "Interest Rate: " + account1.interestRate );
            System.out.println( "Balance: " + account1.balance );

            break;

        case "MakePayment":
            MakePaymentStruct structData2 = new MakePaymentStruct();
            structData2.acntNum = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] );
            structData2.payment = Double.parseDouble( inputArgs[ 2 ] );
            structData2.accounts = accounts;

            structData2 = ( MakePaymentStruct ) ( ( MakePaymentCommand ) commands.get( 2 ) ).DoCommand( ( Object ) structData2 );

            if ( structData2 == null ) {
                System.out.println( "Could not find account #" + Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] ) + "." );
                break;
            }

            Account account2 = structData2.account;

            System.out.println( "New balance for account #" + account2.acntNum + " is " + account2.balance );

            break;

        case "IncrementMonth":
            IncrementMonthStruct structData3 = new IncrementMonthStruct();
            structData3.acntNum = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] );
            structData3.accounts = accounts;

            structData3 = ( IncrementMonthStruct ) ( ( IncrementMonthCommand ) commands.get( 3 ) ).DoCommand( ( Object ) structData3 );

            if ( structData3 == null ) {
                System.out.println( "Could not find account #" + Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] ) + "." );
                break;
            }

            Account account3 = structData3.account;

            System.out.println( "Added the monthly interest for account #" + account3.acntNum );

            break;

        case "CloseAccount":
            OpenAccountStruct structData4 = new OpenAccountStruct();
            structData4.acntNum = Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] );
            structData4.accounts = accounts;

            structData4 = ( OpenAccountStruct ) ( ( OpenAccountCommand ) commands.get( 1 ) ).DoCommand( ( Object ) structData4 );

            if ( structData4 == null ) {
                System.out.println( "Could not find account #" + Integer.parseInt( inputArgs[ 1 ] ) + "." );
                break;
            }

            Account account4 = structData4.account;

            if ( account4.balance > 0.00d ) {
                System.out.println( "There is still money that needs to be payed!" );
                break;
            }

            accounts.remove( account4 );

            break;

        default:
            run = false;
            break;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: what's in the stacktrace in the exception?

Comment: Do *any* java programs work on your computer?

Comment: It says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Bank.main(Bank.java:10) pointing out that there is an error at commands.add( new CreateNewCommand() );

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, and java programs do work on my computer

Answer (score 2):

Where are you defining `commands` list? you have a Declaration but you're not creating anything as far as I can see.

```
public static List< ICommand > commands;


commands = new List< .... ?
```

I can see you defining the commands themselves, but not the list.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
public static List< ICommand > commands;
```

only declares the `List`

At some point, you need to initialize `commands` like so:

```
commands = new ArrayList< ICommand >();
```

This can be done in your `main` method:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    commands = new ArrayList< ICommand >();
    commands.add( new CreateNewCommand() );
```

or when you declare `commands`:

```
public static List< Account > accounts;
public static List< ICommand > commands = new ArrayList< ICommand >();

public static void main( String[] args ) {
```

You also need to initialize `accounts`. You can do this the same way you initialize `commands`.

The code you have shouldn't work on *any* computer. Are you sure that you are running the *exact* same code on both computers?

Comment: I have a class called ICommand, but where in my main method would i place commands = new List< ICommand >;

Comment: @user3010894 The same place I put it in my code above: between `public static void main( String[] args ) {` and `commands.add( new CreateNewCommand() );`

Comment: @user3010894 To be less specific: In almost all cases, you need to initialize an object before you can use it. When running the code, everything in the `main` method is done in order, so you can initialize `commands` anywhere before it is used. The only place in the `main` method before `commands` is used is right in the beginning, between `public static void main( String[] args ) {` and `commands.add( new CreateNewCommand() );`